# How SQL Server Express windows service works, when install/uninstall SQL Server 2005/2008?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

As part of my windows application installation, I install SQL Server 2005 and it creates the database for my application (`projectdb.mdf` file).

Assume for different application I have another installation like SQL Server 2008/2012 installed in my system. When I install on my machine for first time freshly, I could see my installer installs SQL Server 2005 and creates the `.mdf` file as well.

But from the next time on, when I uninstall both my application and SQL Server 2005 from control panel, and install it again with the same installer, sometimes I see SQL Server 2005 is not getting installed. I dug around a bit and checked, in my installer code, before installing the SQL Server, I am checking for connection to the database is successful or not?

Since the SQL Server (SQL Server Express) service is up and running, the connection to the database is successful and the installer is not installing the SQL Server 2005. Here is the code snippet.

```
strConn = "Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=false;";

SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection();
bool isSQLConnectionSuccessful = true;
Conn.ConnectionString = strConn;

try
{
   Conn.Open();
}
catch
{
   isSQLConnectionSuccessful = false;
}
```

On basing on the `isSQLConnectionSuccessful` status, we are going ahead to decide on SQL Server 2005 installation.

There is a possibility like, in my machine, I might be having other version of SQL Server (2008/2012). Does it effects SQL Server Express service to be up and running?

Is it the fine approach, if the `projectdb.mdf` exists and not installing the SQL Server 2005 because the SQL Server (SQL Server Express) is up and running.

Even from my application side, until the SQL Server Express service is up and running, I am not seeing any issue while interacting with the databases.

Please help me in resolving my conflicts. I googled it but not able to find the appropriate answer for my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to install multiple copies of SQL Server on a single machine, you need to use different **database instances**. E.g. your SQL Server 2005 Express could use `SQLEXPRESS`, while your 2012 version could e.g. use `SQL2012` or something like that. Using instances, you can have multiple versions of SQL Server on the same machine, and they won't overwrite each other when installing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc_s, i have another question, so once the database is created (.mdf), we dont need the SQL server installation since we have SQL Server service running in the background?

Comment: If you have a `.mdf` file and you want to use it, you **must have** an installed, up-and-running SQL Server instance to handle it.